# transfer CurrentDirectory from un-elevated script to elevated one

Tags: vbscript, uac

I need to copy my file "manufacturer.bmp", wich is located in the same directory as the script (in my flash drive), to the `system32` directory.

I succeed, in getting the variables `sourcefile`, `destinationdirectory`, and to elevate my script, but when I elevate it, my `sourcefile` variable is lost, because of the use of `CurrentDirectory`, which differs in this mode.

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
sourcefile = fso.buildpath(CurrentDirectory, "manufacturer.bmp")
MsgBox(sourcefile)

'Checks if the script is running elevated (UAC)
Function isElevated
  Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set whoami = shell.Exec("whoami /groups")
  Set whoamiOutput = whoami.StdOut
  strWhoamiOutput = whoamiOutput.ReadAll

  If InStr(1, strWhoamiOutput, "S-1-16-12288", vbTextCompare) Then 
    isElevated = True
  Else
    isElevated = False
  End If
End Function

'Re-runs the process prompting for priv elevation on re-run
Sub uacPrompt
  'Check if we need to run in C or W script
  interpreter = "wscript.exe"
  If InStr(1, WScript.FullName, "CScript", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    interpreter = "wscript.exe"
  Else
    interpreter = "cscript.exe"
  End If

  'Start a new instance with an elevation prompt first
  Set shellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  shellApp.ShellExecute interpreter, Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & _
    Chr(34) & " uac", "", "runas", 1

  'End the non-elevated instance
  WScript.Quit
End Sub

'Make sure we are running elevated, prompt if not
If Not isElevated Then uacPrompt

destinationdir = fso.buildpath(shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%"), _
                 "system32")
MsgBox(destinationdir)

fso.CopyFile sourcefile, destinationdir
```

Any idea of how to push my sourcefile var to the child elevated script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method allows you to specify the working directory as the 3<sup>rd</sup> argument, so you can pass the current directory to the elevated script and build the `sourcefile` path after elevation. Also, your code could be streamlined quite a bit.

```
Const HKLM   = &h80000002
Const DELETE = &h10000

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")
reg.CheckAccess HKLM, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet", DELETE, isAdmin

If Not isAdmin Then
  If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName, _
      Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " uac", _
      sh.CurrentDirectory, "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit 0
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Privilege elevation failed!"
    WScript.Quit 1
  End If
End If

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src = fso.BuildPath(sh.CurrentDirectory, "manufacturer.bmp")
dst = fso.buildpath(sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%"), "system32")

fso.CopyFile src, dst & "\"
```

**Edit:** or at least that's how it would work if you weren't elevating the process. According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/11/6648397.aspx) from Raymond Chen the start directory is ignored when elevating processes, so that malicious DLLs from the current directory aren't loaded into elevated processes by mistake. Meaning that you must pass the working directory "manually", like this:

```
Const HKLM   = &h80000002
Const DELETE = &h10000

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")
reg.CheckAccess HKLM, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet", DELETE, isAdmin

If Not isAdmin Then
  If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName, _
      Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " " & _
      Chr(34) & sh.CurrentDirectory & Chr(34), , "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit 0
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Privilege elevation failed!"
    WScript.Quit 1
  End If
End If

sh.CurrentDirectory = WScript.Arguments(0)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src = fso.BuildPath(sh.CurrentDirectory, "manufacturer.bmp")
dst = fso.buildpath(sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%"), "system32")

fso.CopyFile src, dst & "\"
```

Note that since your destination path is a folder, it *must* have a trailing backslash (as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and for your time, I've tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work. I added message boxes to output the variables in order to verify. When the elevated script runs, the workind directory remains C:\windows\system32 and I can't access the given bmp file with it relative path.
My idea to pass through that situation is to temporarily copy the bmp file to a fixed temp folder and then to copy it in System32 folder when elevated.

Comment: It works with the temporary directory :
If Not isAdmin Then
  sourcefile = fso.buildpath(CurrentDirectory, "manufacturer.bmp")
  fso.CopyFile sourcefile, temploc & "\"
  If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
[...]
Else
  temploc = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%")
  sourcefile = fso.buildpath(temploc, "manufacturer.bmp")
  dst = fso.buildpath(sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%"), "system32")
  fso.CopyFile sourcefile, dst & "\"  
End If

Comment: @Letouane Sorry for the late response. See answer for an explanation and a workaround.

Comment: Tried your answer and it works many thanks Ansgar (not any matter relating to "late response", you provide me help) !